# Code question: LCD keypad Shield. How do I define the buttons?

Tags: lcd, code-review, keypad

I am trying to adapt a [alarm clock sketch](https://github.com/embeddedlab786/Real_Time_Clock_With_Alarm/blob/master/Real_Time_Clock_With_Alarm.ino) that used external buttons, but I would like to utilize a LCD Keypad Shield.  The data sheet says all the buttons are on pin A0, so every button is "set time" in the original sketch.

After reading [this post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/48587/how-do-i-control-the-buttons-on-an-arduino-lcd-keypad-shield)

I found the values when I press each button, :

```
Right    0
Up     100
Down   257
Left   410
Select 640
```

and have tried to define them by modifying the existing code:

```
LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7); //Arduino pins to lcd
#define bt_time   A0
#define bt_up     A1
#define bt_down   A2
#define bt_alarm  A3
```

With:

```
LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7); //Arduino pins to lcd
int lcd_key     = 0;
int adc_key_in  = 0;
#define bt_time   0
#define bt_up     1
#define bt_down   2
#define bt_alarm  3

#define buzzer 10

int read_LCD_buttons()
{
 adc_key_in = analogRead(0);      // read the value from the sensor 
 // my buttons when read are centered at these valies: 0, 144, 329, 504, 741
 // we add approx 50 to those values and check to see if we are close
 if (adc_key_in < 50)   return bt_time;  
 if (adc_key_in < 150)  return bt_up; 
 if (adc_key_in < 307)  return bt_down; 
 if (adc_key_in < 690)  return bt_alarm; 

}
```

I got this from [here](https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/index.php?title=LCD_Keypad_Shield)

It doesn't work.... when you press the buttons nothing happens.

It up loads with no errors, but the buttons don't do anything.

Please help, your my only hope.

Edit:
The linked "Real_Time_Clock_With_Alarm.ino" is the source file, all I have changed is the above code.  It works except I can't interact with it...  because no buttons....  I have also tested the hardware with other sketch and it works as expected.

Comment: What do you return if no button is pressed? And how can it ever be not less than 4600 when the ADC gives you 0-1023 (or 0-4096 on some better boards)?

Comment: To true, typo it should have been 690 not 4600.....

Comment: You haven't answered my first question though: what do you return if no button is pressed?

Comment: you code says `analogRead(0)` ... is that same as analogRead(A0)?

Comment: What does “It doesn't work” mean? Could you please write a minimal test sketch, post it here, explain how it behaves and how that is different from what you expect?

Comment: @jsotola In short, yes. In more detail:  Those shields are a 5V design that practically work with the UNO/Leonardo/Mega boards, all of which use a wiring_analog.c implementation that behaves the same for `A0` and `0`.

Comment: In your current revision, you're checking `< 307` and then `< 690` but **two** of your observed readings 410 and 640 sit between these numbers.